# Issues flashing a STM32F Discovery using Eclipse under Ubuntu

Tags: stm32f4discovery

I'm using Eclipse under Ubuntu 14.04 to work on an STM32F4DISCOVERY I have set the system to flash my blinky project to the Discovery. After building the project I go to Run-> External Tools and hit Run to down load the code to flash but I get the following message on the Console window:

```
invalid command line
stlinkv1 command line: ./st-flash [--debug] [--reset] {read|write} /dev/sgX path addr <size>
stlinkv1 command line: ./st-flash [--debug] /dev/sgX erase
stlinkv2 command line: ./st-flash [--debug] [--reset] {read|write} path addr <size>
stlinkv2 command line: ./st-flash [--debug] erase
                   use hex format for addr and <size>
```

The External Tool Configurations I'm using is as follows:
    Main-> Location /usr/local/bin/st-flash
    Main -> Working Directory ${project_loc}/Release
    Main -> Arguments:write${project_name}.bin 0x8000000

I have ran the following commands to check that everything is set correctly:

```
julio@julio-virtual-machine:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0483:3748 STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

julio@julio-virtual-machine:~$ dmesg|tail -n 6
[ 3558.411428] usb 2-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using uhci_hcd
[ 3558.690133] usb 2-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=3748
[ 3558.690143] usb 2-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3558.690148] usb 2-2.1: Product: STM32 STLink
[ 3558.690152] usb 2-2.1: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
[ 3558.690156] usb 2-2.1: SerialNumber: P\xffffffc3\xffffffbf\xffffffbfr\x06PfPQCH#\xffffffc2\xffffff87\xffffff87
julio@julio-virtual-machine:~/ARM ToolChain/gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_9-2015q2/bin$ arm-none-eabi-gcc  --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (4.8.2-14ubuntu1+6) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Could you help me check if I'm missing something or if I'm doing it in a wrong way?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Dumb question but did you try running st-flash from the cmdline?  Does that work?

Comment: yes, when I run st-flash in the cmdline it gives me the same massage invalid command line
stlinkv1 command line: ./st-flash [--debug] [--reset] {read|write} /dev/sgX path addr <size>
stlinkv1 command line: ./st-flash [--debug] /dev/sgX erase
stlinkv2 command line: ./st-flash [--debug] [--reset] {read|write} path addr <size>
stlinkv2 command line: ./st-flash [--debug] erase

Comment: Well, there you go.  Get the command to work in cmdline first.  You probably have the parameters wrong.  Take a look at the help for the program and get it work that way first.  You're just trying to get it to flash, right?  The command should be something like `st-flash write <0xaddr> <size>`